# Using Unmanaged C++lib with C#

Tags: c#, marshalling

I'm still trying use a C++ unmanaged dll with C#.

My problem is :

i got a function (from my dll) : 
C++ :

```
INT APIENTRY ReadPIC(HANDLE hComPort, PIC *pic, BYTE PacketData[])
{
BYTE InData[MAX_PACKET];        //Allocate for one packet
INT RetStatus;
INT DatCount;
INT DatCount2 = 0;

switch (pic->BootCmd){
    case COMMAND_READPM: 
    case COMMAND_READEE: 
    case COMMAND_READCFG: 
        break;
    default: return ERROR_INVALID_COMMAND;
}

//Limit to 1 or 2 bytes per addr
if(!pic->BytesPerAddr) return ERROR_BPA_TOO_SMALL;
if(pic->BytesPerAddr > 2) return ERROR_BPA_TOO_BIG;

if(pic->BytesPerBlock < pic->BytesPerAddr) return ERROR_BLOCK_TOO_SMALL;
if(pic->BootDatLen > MAX_PACKET - 6) return ERROR_PACKET_TOO_BIG;

//Build header
InData[0] = pic->BootCmd;
InData[1] = pic->BootDatLen / pic->BytesPerAddr;
InData[2] = (BYTE)(pic->BootAddr & 0xFF);
InData[3] = (BYTE)((pic->BootAddr & 0xFF00) / 0x100);
InData[4] = (BYTE)((pic->BootAddr & 0xFF0000) / 0x10000);

RetStatus = SendGetPacket(hComPort, InData, 5, MAX_PACKET, pic->MaxRetrys);

if(RetStatus < 0) return RetStatus;

for (DatCount = 5; DatCount < RetStatus - 1; DatCount++){
    PacketData[DatCount2] = InData[DatCount];
    DatCount2++;
}

return DatCount2;
```

}

C# implementation :

```
       [DllImport(@"PICBOOT.dll")]
       public static extern short ReadPIC(int hComPort, ref PIC pic, ref byte PacketData);

        DevID[0] = (byte)CMD_READ_VERSION;
        DevID[1] = (byte)0;
        short RetStat;
        PIC pic = new PIC();
        pic.BootAddr = 0x3FFFFE;
        pic.BootCmd = (byte)CMD_READ_PROG_MEM;
        pic.BootDatLen = (byte)2;
        pic.MaxRetrys = 3;
        pic.BytesPerBlock = 1;
        pic.BytesPerAddr = 1;


        RetStat = com.Dll_PIC_interface.ReadPIC(PicBoots.PortHandle, ref pic, ref DevID[0]);
```

I also have a VB example of the same function :

```
    ReDim DevID(10) As Byte
Dim RetStat

Dim picb As PIC

DevID(0) = CMD_READ_VERSION
DevID(1) = 0
picb.BootAddr = &H3FFFFE
picb.BootCmd = CMD_READ_PROG_MEM
picb.BootDatLen = 2
picb.MaxRetrys = PicBootS.MaxRetry
picb.BytesPerBlock = 1
picb.BytesPerAddr = 1
RetStat = ReadPIC(PicBootS.PortHandle, picb, DevID(0))
If RetStat <= 0 Then
    ReadDeviceID = "0"
Else
    ReadDeviceID = CStr(((DevID(1) * 256) + DevID(0)) \ 32)
End If
```

The C# one throw an error (-11 )who must tie in : #define ERROR_BPA_TOO_BIG     -11

this is the first time i have to use unmanaged dll, don't realy know why it doesn't know, i think i'm pretty near form the VB example.

The C++ struct implementation

```
//PIC structure used for some functions
 typedef struct _PIC {
BYTE BootCmd;
BYTE BootDatLen;        //Number of bytes to read/write
DWORD BootAddr;         //24 bit memory address (Prog or EE)
BYTE BytesPerBlock;
BYTE BytesPerAddr;
WORD MaxRetrys;         //Number of retries before failure
 } PIC;
```

mine :

```
    public struct PIC
{
    public byte BootCmd;//{ get; set; }
    public byte BootDatLen ;//{ get; set; }
    public ulong BootAddr ; //{ get; set; }
    public byte BytesPerBlock; //{ get; set; }
    public byte BytesPerAddr ; //{ get; set; }
    public ushort MaxRetrys;  //{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `BootAddr` should be `uint`, not `ulong`.

Comment: Where can i share a +1 for u ? thx it's working i didn't saw it i'm so sad... too much time wasted !

Comment: Post the solution as answer and get some rep ;p I have enough.